Convergence of $\frac 1{H_n} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k \{kx\}$

Question: Let $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k$ be the harmonic numbers and let $\{x\}:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ be the fractional part of $x$. Can we show that the sequence of functions
$$f_n(x) := \frac 1{H_n} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k \{kx\}$$
converges for any (real) $x$ as $n\to\infty$?

This question was inspired by another question on the site (which I think has been deleted) about properties of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k \{kx\}$. I noticed when plotting the function that, after normalizing by the harmonic numbers, it seems to converge to this rather beautiful fractal function. Below it is shown at $n=300$.
I think there are many interesting questions about this function (Is it discontinuous exactly at the rationals? What is the structure of the self-similarity? What is the "central" curve, and what are the upper and lower envelopes? Does it have a Hausdorff dimension (is that even a thing for discontinuous graphs...?)? etc...) ---- but first and foremost one should show convergence. Somehow it seems to me connected to the equidistribution theorem, but I don't know. Or can we simply estimate that the increments of the sequence are small enough to guarantee convergence?
Note: Obviously the sequence is bounded between $0$ and $1$ for all $n$ and $x$, and it has a period of $1$. However, it is not monotone in $n$, and the sequence of differences is not alternating either. I thought it might be fruitful perhaps to study it as a series of differences $f_1 + \sum_{n\ge 1}(f_{n+1}-f_n)$.
Alternatively, a link or keyword to any information on this function would be just as appreciated.

EDIT:
Below is the true limit for comparison, plotted from Yalikesi's answer. Notably, all points converge to $\le \frac12$, so it looks quite different from the finite sums in that regard. However, you can see how the largest downwards peaks nearer the center of the graph are beginning to show the true pattern in the image above.
Also notably, if $f(x)$ is Thomae's function, then the limit turned out to be $\frac{1 - f(x)}{2}$. Pretty cool if you ask me ;)

PS: Excuse the low image quality. It looks much better on my end before I upload it... IDK how to improve it.

Interesting question! I looked at the values of the limit for $x=1/k, k=2, 3, ...$, approached from below, and found $f_{n\to\inf}(1/k)=\frac{k-1}{2k}$. This is in good agreement with the first few values of your graph. For smaller values of $x$ your fixed number $n=300$ is not suffient to reproduce the limit.

@Dr.WolfgangHintze That is indeed in agreement with the accepted answer :)

@Milton. Happy about it. I have calculated the result by myself during the last few days. It was a nice exercise.

I found the related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5010898/how-to-show-nx-leq-sum-i-1n-frac-1i-ix#5010898

@Milton Thank you for pointing out this related question. While I can show that from ${2x}\le 2{x}$ or $\frac {1}{2} {2x}\le {x}$ follows by adding $\frac {1}{2} {2 x}$ that ${2x}\le {x} + \frac{1}{2}{2x}$ I wasn't able to extend the result to $n\gt 2$.

By chance, a number of helpful results can be found in this article on random permutation matrices by Kelly Wieand, and the sources cited there.
First, the convergence can be established via Theorem 3: let $\omega_k$ be a bounded sequence of positive real numbers, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \omega_k = L < \infty
$$
implies
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\ln n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\omega_k}{k} = L.
$$
In your case, $\omega_k = \{k x\}$, and the equidistribution theorem states that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \omega_k \to \int_0^1 x \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{2}$ for irrational $x$. Since $\frac{H_n}{\ln n} \to 1$, it means that $f_n(x) \to \frac{1}{2}$ for irrational $x$ as $n\to\infty$.
If $x$ is rational, $x = \frac{p}{q}$, then $\left\{\frac{k p}{q}\right\}$ can only be $0, \frac{1}{q}, \frac{2}{q}, ..., \frac{q-1}{q}$, so
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left\{\frac{k p}{q}\right\} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=0}^{q-1} \sum_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq n \\ kp \equiv r \; \mathrm{mod}\; q}} \frac{r}{q} = 
\sum_{r=0}^{q-1} \frac{r}{q} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n 1{\left\{ kp \equiv r \; \mathrm{mod}\; q\right\}} = \\ =
\sum_{r=0}^{q-1} \frac{r}{q} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^{n p} 1{\left\{ m \equiv r \; \mathrm{mod}\; q\right\}} 1{\left\{ m \equiv 0 \; \mathrm{mod}\; p\right\}} \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \sum_{r=0}^{q-1} \frac{r}{q} \cdot \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{q^2} \frac{q(q-1)}{2} = \frac{q-1}{2q}.
$$
Same is mentioned in the A.1 appendix section of the article.
So, $f_n(x)$ converges for all $x\in [0,1]$, and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}, & x \in [0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}, \\
\frac{q-1}{2q}, & x = \frac{p}{q}, q \in \mathbb{N}.
\end{cases}
$$
Hence, $f(x)$ is discontinuous at rationals, but is continuous at each irrational $x$: if $x_n \to x$, then $f(x_n) = f(x)$ for irrational $x_n$, and $f(x_n) = \frac{q_n-1}{2q_n} \to \frac{1}{2}$ for rational $x_n = \frac{p_n}{q_n}$ since $q_n \to +\infty$.
Interestingly, the plots for finite $n$ are misleading. In the first place, any plotting tool operates with rational numbers only, hence it fails to capture the function's behaviour at irrational points. Another possible reason is that convergence is very slow. Same Theorem 3 states that if $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \omega_k$ converges to $L$ at the rate $\frac{1}{n^b}$ for some $b>0$, then $\frac{1}{\ln n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\omega_k}{k}$ converges to $L$ only at the rate of $\frac{1}{\ln n}$.
As for any kind of self-similarity,
$$
f_n(x) + f_n(1-x) = \frac{1}{H_n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\left(
\{kx\} + \{k(1-x)\} \right) = \\ =
\frac{1}{H_n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\left(
kx - \lfloor{kx}\rfloor + k(1-x) - \lfloor{k(1-x)}\rfloor \right) = \\ = 
\frac{1}{H_n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\left(
k - \lfloor {kx}\rfloor - k - \lfloor {-kx}\rfloor \right) =
\frac{1}{H_n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{-1}{k}\left(
\lfloor {kx}\rfloor + \lfloor {-kx}\rfloor \right) = 1
$$
if all $x, 2x, ..., n x \not\in \mathbb{Z}$ -- or, equivalently, $f_n(1-x) = 1 - f_n(x)$.

Thanks! That's a pretty neat theorem I wasn't aware of. Before reading your answer I was able to come up with a much more complicated expression for the exact value at rationals, but I had no idea it would simplify to this. For anyone interested, there is a typo in the proof of the linked theorem: It should say $j<i$ instead of $i<j$ in $(3.4)$. And I think $2K$ could be replaced by just $K$ in $(3.7)$, if I'm not mistaken.

Also, if $f(x)$ is Thomae's function, then this is nothing but $\frac{1-f(x)}2$. I never thought I'd encounter Thomae's function in the wild :D

@Milten you are right about $(3.4)$, but $2K$ in $(3.7)$ is due to $|s_k - L| \leq s_k + L$ and $s_k, L \leq K$ by definition. As for the plot, it is quite interesting that $f(x) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$, but $f_n(x)$ "oscillates" around $\frac{1}{2}$ at rational points. You can plot, e.g., $f_n(1/9)$ and $f_n(8/9)$ up to some very large $n$ in one plot - both are slowly converging to $\frac{8}{18}$, but first is increasing-ish and second is decreasing-ish.

Ah, that more than likely explains why they wrote $2K$. However, since $s_k, L\in[0,K]$ it’s also true directly that $|s_k - L|\le K$. It doesn’t matter for the argument of course, I only mention it because I myself got tripped up for a moment when reading the proof

About the last paragraph, we do in fact have $f_n(1-x) = 1 - f_n(x^-)$ for all $x$.

Direct calculation for rational $x$ (sketch):
Let $x=\frac pq$ (in lowest terms) and $a_k = \frac 1k \{kx\}$. One checks that
$$
H_{nq}f_{nq}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{nq}a_i = \sum_{r=1}^q\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{r+kq}
= \sum_{r=1}^q\left\{\frac{rp}q\right\}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{r+kq}.
$$
Now show that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{r+kq} = \frac1qH_{nq} + O(1)$ (where the constant is independent of $r$ and $n$). And since $p$ and $q$ are coprime:
$$
\sum_{r=1}^q \left\{\frac{rp}q\right\} 
= \sum_{r=1}^{q-1} \left\{\frac rq\right\}
= \sum_{r=1}^{q-1} \frac rq
= \frac {q-1}2.
$$
It now basically follows that $\lim f_n(\frac pq) = \frac{q-1}{2q}$, although there are a few more details to fill in (what happens at $f_N$ for $N\ne nq$?).
For the irrational case, I think one will have to mimic the proof of the theorem mentioned by Yalikesi. At least I can't see a way around it.
